# Excel VBA ListObjects Add Range with multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, range, addition

I'm a new member although I visit this website a lot.
I can't add a new item to my listobject if I choose random cells. For example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="ErrorExample", _
    RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1;Sheet1!$A$2;Sheet1!$A$3"
```

But if I choose cells in the same range I don't get the runtime error 1004... For example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="RightExample", _
    RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3"
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a **Defined Name** to the workbook.  It has nothing to do with a `ListObject`.

The reason you are getting the error it that you are concatenating your range addresses with semicolons instead of commas.

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ThisWorks", RefersTo:="=Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$A$3"`